# How to handle subset containing an even number of elements?(Find peak problem using divide and conquer)

Tags: algorithm

I have difficult time writing code with Divide & Conquer algorithm. The biggest question is that I don't know how to handle the subset with even number of elements.

A typical problem is "Given an input array nums, where nums[i] ≠ nums[i+1], find a peak element and return its index".

The algorithm on the book says:

**If nums[n/2] < nums[n/2 -1] then only look at left half to find a peak**

**Else if nums[n/2] < nums[n/2 + 1] then only look at right half to find a peak**

**Else n/2 position is a peak**

I don't know how to handle n/2 when n = 2. Because the algorithm seems always to divide the set into 2 parts. It is easy to understand when the subset contains an odd number of elements, say [a,b,c]. I can find the middle elements b and make a comparison. When the subset contains only two elements, say [a, b]. I can't find the middle elements to compare.

To make recursion terminate properly, I add some logic to my python code. I just can't make it in one time. I want to know is there a way to think about the termination condition concerning a subset like [a,b] in my question?

```
class Solution:
def findPeakElement(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    def finder(start, end):
        if start == end:
            return start
        if end - start == 1:
            return end if nums[start] < nums[end] else start
        N = end-start+1
        if(nums[start+N//2]<nums[start+N//2-1]):
            return finder(start,start+N//2-1)
        elif(nums[start+N//2]<nums[start+N//2+1]):
            return finder(start+N//2+1,end)
        else:
            return start+N//2

    return finder(0,len(nums)-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend simplifying your logic and style so it's easier to reason about your code. You're computing `N//2` repeatedly which wastes cycles and is noisy and semantically meaningless. Save the work in a variable called `mid` at the beginning of your function, giving it meaning. Add spacing to your code to reduce visual noise and make it pleasant (and possible) to step through.

As for `start`, `end` and `N`, that's an extra variable to have to think about and manipulate--`start` and `end` are sufficient to handle all cases, and confusing these variables appears to be an issue in your code.

Since you already know the algorithm, you're close to the solution. The parity of the array is not the problem, though--the only issue is (literal!) edge cases when `mid == 0` and `mid == len(nums) - 1`. In both of these cases, there is only one neighbor, so we'd crash if we attempted `nums[mid-1]` and `nums[mid+1]` respectively. Resolving these is a matter of testing that `mid` is not at one end of the array or the other before attempting these comparisons.

Putting it all together, all that needs to happen in the function is:

```
def finder(start, end):
    mid = (start + end) // 2

    if mid > 0 and nums[mid] < nums[mid-1]:
        return finder(start, mid - 1)
    elif mid < end and nums[mid] < nums[mid+1]:
        return finder(mid + 1, end)
    else:
        return mid
```